# ImageMagick montage natural file order

Tags: imagemagick

I am trying to use the ImageMagick montage feature to combine chunks of maps from a game. My issue is that the game's original files are naturally ordered like

part1.png
part2.png
...
part10.png

ImageMagick reads this and will tile part10.png after part1.png. Is there a flag/option to tell IM to read the directory the way I want it to? This is a live code sample of what I'm doing.

```
montage                    \
    -alpha on              \
    -background none       \
    -mode concatenate      \
    -tile x{$grid}         \
    -mattecolor none       \
    {$input_dir}/*.png     \
    {$output_file}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly use `sort -g` (that's *general numeric sort*) to get what you want.

**Test:**

Create 12 dummy files:

```
for i in {1.12} ; do touch ${i}.txt ; done
```

List the files:

```
ls -1 *.txt
  1.txt
  10.txt
  11.txt
  12.txt
  2.txt
  3.txt
  4.txt
  5.txt
  6.txt
  7.txt
  8.txt
  9.txt
```

Use `sort -g` to list them in different order:

```
ls -1 *.txt | sort -g
  1.txt
  2.txt
  3.txt
  4.txt
  5.txt
  6.txt
  7.txt
  8.txt
  9.txt
  10.txt
  11.txt
  12.txt
```

**Real Life:**

Now apply this to solve your problem:

```
montage                                    \
    -alpha on                              \
    -background none                       \
    -mode concatenate                      \
    -tile x{$grid}                         \
    -mattecolor none                       \
     $(ls -1 {$input_dir}/*.png | sort -g) \
     {$output_file}
```

If your `$input_dir` name doesn't contain any spaces, this should work flawlessly.

Comment: In case of "image-1.png" > "image-400.png" `sort -V` did the trick for me .